# Не получается установить Ubuntu на виртуалку

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Когда нажимаю на любой пункт из меню при установке Ubuntu, то появляется просто такой черный экран с мигающим нижним подчеркиваем и никаких больше действий , что делать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ждите. Минут десять хотя бы.

Comment: Ждал минут 15 - все так же само.

Comment: Какая версия VirtualBox? Какая версия Ubuntu? Откуда взят образ? Какая конфигурация виртуальной машины? Какая хост-ОС наконец?

Comment: Virtual Box - 5.2.22
Lubuntu 18.04 Desktop i386
С официального сайта 
Какая конкретно конфигурация?
Хост WIndows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Очень похоже на проблему с видеорежимами. Попробуйте отключить 3D ускорение в настройках виртуалки.

Ну а еще, поговаривают, что нужно проверить, правильно-ли выбрана битность в конфигурации VM, и то, что вы собственно ставите, быть может выставлено 32 бита, а пытаетесь 64-битный дистрибутив накатить

Comment: 3D ускорение отключено. Доступна только 32 битная версия в VM, собственно  образ тоже 32 бита Lubuntu 18.04 Desktop i386.

Comment: Скачивал 4 разных образа , на всех тоже самое , скачивал с официальных сайтов.